# Вернуть результат работы команды SELECT

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Предположим, что есть таблица со столбцами Имя, Фамилия и Возраст.
Могу ли я посредством выполнения команды в стиле

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestDB WHERE AGE=25";
```

вернуть имя в текстовое поле?

Comment: Нет. Выполнение запроса всегда возвращает набор записей (по сути - коллекция коллекций), даже если это одна запись с единственным полем. В текстовое поле такая конструкция не влезет, надо итерать и извлекать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Показанный запрос явно вернёт не одну запись и не одно поле. Причём ни порядок записей, ни порядок полей не определены, т.е. результат, который вернёт ExecuteScalar - недетерминированный. Посему даже не рассматривал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можете, только надо вместо `*` написать то самое извлекаемое поле:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT [Name] FROM TestDB WHERE age=25";

string value = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
// или
string value = (string)await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
```

Только учтите, что таким образом вы вытащите только одну из подходящих записей.

Comment: только что провернул операцию через команду: using (SqlDataReader reader= command.ExecuteReader())

Comment: Ещё я бы предложил добавить в текст запроса какой-нить ORDER BY - скажем, по id. Для хоть какой-то определённости.